# Which LaTeX package provides this text typeface?

Tags: fonts, typography

The typeface is the same as the one here: [LaTeX font for 'old-fashioned' script characters](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/110173/latex-font-for-old-fashioned-script-characters)

I have copied the image from that post here.

[image: Page from the book in question]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: [Computer modern roman fibonacci](http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/cmfibonacci/) *seems* similar (but I don't think they are identical).

Comment: Is that book typeset in TeX? If not, this question does not have anything to do with TeX, and is just a question about identifying a font.

Comment: @Manuel That is what I am trying to ascertain.

Comment: @PaulGessler I am not interested in the math symbols, only the text font.

Comment: May be a “Century font”. Century Expanded is quite similar.

Comment: @Manuel: good hint, looks like "Century Schoolbook"

Comment: @bersch and Manuel: Thank you very much, that will fit my use quite well.

Comment: At first sight I thought Century Schoolbook was thicker than that, but *may be* that's the font...

Comment: @Manuel: fonts are being modified during time, i'd look in an older distro for that.