# how can i get this math symbol?

Tags: symbols

I want to know how to type the middle symbol below. I tried detexify but it didn't get what I wanted.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.  This is a script "P".  Unfortunately, I don't remember which font it's in.

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/110193.

Comment: It could be mathtime pro 2 curly, see the first answer here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/58098/what-are-all-the-font-styles-i-can-use-in-math-mode

Comment: See [the documentation for `mathalpha`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/mathalpha/doc/mathalpha-doc.pdf) and [`unicode-math`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/unicode-math/unimath-symbols.pdf) for specimens of most of the script fonts available.